# How to list all "items" in a StreamReader in JObject?

Tags: c#, json, api, json.net

How do I retrieve the "totalResult" from a StreamReader in a JObject? In the "JO" variable, I only get 50 values, but the total says that it has 227 values.

```
string link = "https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLTPg64KdGgYivEK9avhUlxsaJhD0TfpxW";
string Url = String.Format("https://api.youtubemultidownloader.com/playlist?url={0}&nextPageToken=", link);
HttpWebRequest wb = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Url);
wb.Method = "GET";
wb.KeepAlive = true;
wb.Proxy = null;
wb.Referer = "https://youtubemultidownloader.com/playlist.html";
wb.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:58.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/58.0";
var value = new StreamReader(wb.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
JObject JO = JObject.Parse(value);
JObject Videos = JObject.Parse(JO["items"].ToString());
```

Just to be clearer, I'm trying to recover all the videos from a YouTube playlist and for that I'm relying on an API from this site [youtubemultidownloader.com](http://youtubemultidownloader.com), which means that all the videos are in the variable "value" which are then passed to a "JO" variable and finally get Children () from the "Videos" variable.

How do I get all the "items" of a "totalResults"? Because the total of "items" should be the total of videos that are within the playlist. I have a total of 227 videos of the Playlist, but when I count the "items" that have in the videos variable, only present 50.

```
int count = Videos.Count;

var RetDic = new Dictionary<string, string>();
foreach (var v in Videos.Children())
{
     string Video_ID = v.First["id"].ToString();
     string Video_Title = v.First["title"].ToString();
     RetDic.Add(Video_ID, Video_Title);
}
```

I'm using the "Newtonsoft.Json.6.0.6" package

Comment: Hello, and welcome to stackoverflow.  Might you please [edit] your question to include the returned JSON as **text** rather than as a screenshot?  It's policy here not to to use images for this purpose, see [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500) and [*Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why.

Comment: Ok, I'll edit my comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is about pagination of api, look `"resultsPerPage": 50`
downloader page that you use makes this,

get first result and if total > resultPerPage som it make a new request using `"nextPageToken":"CGQQAA"` 
example 
146 items (total) -> 3 request
50 without nextPageToken return nextpageToken

```
string.Format("https://api.yoursite.com/playlist?url={0}&nextPageToken=", link)
```

50 second package of videos making request with nextpagetoken

```
string.Format("https://api.yoursite.com/playlist?url={0}&nextPageToken={1}", link, nextPageToken)
```

Json Result Example

```
  {
     "nextPageToken":"CGQQAA",
     "totalResults":146,
     "resultsPerPage":50,
     "currentResults":50,
     "items":{
        "0":{
           "id":"wh-uYV6YprA",
           "title":"Private video"
        },
        "1":{
           "id":"C6H0emVJtSw",
           "title":"Ya No Entiendo Nada - Al2 (2010) Los Aldeanos"
        },
        "2":{
           "id":"mhHES-k7Trg",
           "title":"El B [Los Aldeanos]- America"
        },
  /* ... */
        "47":{
           "id":"0IbK43e3vXs",
           "title":"VIOLADORES DEL VERSO - 8 LINEAS (CANAL BOA)"
        },
        "48":{
           "id":"6xCL98XMq9Q",
           "title":"SFDK (Zatu) - Cuando todo acabe (con El Chojin - Colabora Jefe De La M) [Lista de invitados(2011)]"
        },
        "49":{
           "id":"31WFa51c4Lk",
           "title":"Nach - Los Años Luz (con Diana Feria) - Un Dia En Suburbia"
        }
     },
     "status":true
  }
```

You can make some like this

```
var playlist = GetPlayList("https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLTPg64KdGgYivEK9avhUlxsaJhD0TfpxW");
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(playlist.Items.ToList()))

    public string MakeRequest(string link, string nextPage="")
    {
        string url = string.Format("https://api.youtubemultidownloader.com/playlist?url={0}&nextPageToken={1}", link, nextPage);
        HttpWebRequest wb = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        wb.Method = "GET";
        wb.KeepAlive = true;
        wb.Proxy = null;
        wb.Referer = "https://youtubemultidownloader.com/playlist.html";
        wb.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:58.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/58.0";
        var value = new StreamReader(wb.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
        return value;
    }

    public PlayList GetPlayList(string link)
    {
        var json = MakeRequest(link);
        var playList = PlayList.FromJson(json);
        while (playList.Items.Count < playList.TotalResults)
        {
            json = MakeRequest(link, playList.NextPageToken);
            var newPagePlayList = PlayList.FromJson(json);
            playList.NextPageToken = newPagePlayList.NextPageToken;
            // playList.Items = playList.Items.Concat(newPagePlayList.Items).ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value);
            var index = 1;
            playList.Items = playList.Items.Concat(newPagePlayList.Items).ToDictionary((kvp) => (index++).ToString(), kvp => kvp.Value);
        }

        return playList;
    }
```

Converters

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using System.Globalization;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;

public partial class PlayList
{
    [JsonProperty("totalResults")]
    public long TotalResults { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("resultsPerPage")]
    public long ResultsPerPage { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("nextPageToken")]
    public string NextPageToken { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("currentResults")]
    public long CurrentResults { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("items")]
    public Dictionary<string, Item> Items { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("status")]
    public bool Status { get; set; }
}

public partial class Item
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public override string ToString() {
       return string.Format("{0} -> {1}", Id, Title);
    }
}

public partial class PlayList
{
    public static PlayList FromJson(string json) => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PlayList>(json, Converter.Settings);
}

public static class Serialize
{
    public static string ToJson(this PlayList self) => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(self, Converter.Settings);
}

internal static class Converter
{
    public static readonly JsonSerializerSettings Settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        MetadataPropertyHandling = MetadataPropertyHandling.Ignore,
        DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None,
        Converters = {
            new IsoDateTimeConverter { DateTimeStyles = DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal }
        },
    };
}
```

**Update 2018/8/06**
Update concatenation items by request, fixing duplicate keys

Comment: Many thanks for the Post! Within the GetPlayList () method on the part of >> **(playList.Items = playList.Items.Concat(newPagePlayList.Items).ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value)** << gives a warning saying **"An item with the same key has already been added."** That is, the dictionary already has values with the same key. How can I resolve this error?

Comment: @sYsTeM I make a fix about concat items, I tested it